# Opening panel of another form by button of the main form in c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

There are 2 windows forms, one is the main form and another is the subform. In the subform, there is 4 different panel Panel 1,2,3 and 4.In the main form there is one Button.

**what I want to do:**

I want to open the 2nd panel of subform by clicking the button of the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to keep a reference variable to your subform, put it in your main form, and set its value when you open the subform, like this:

```cs
private Form _subForm;

private void OpenSubForm()
{
    _subForm = new SubForm();
    _subForm.Show();
}
```

and then you could use it to access your subform's panels from your main form:

```cs
private void ButtonClick()
{
    _subForm.panel1.Show();
}
```